# In Rally SDK 2, how do I update an array field, like on Artifacts for Changeset?

Tags: javascript, rally

So, I made a model for a changeset, get a changeset with 2 artifacts and fetch the Artifacts field.  When I console log that, I get two items.  I have another item ( a task ) that I push into this field.  When I console log the artifacts array, I get three items.

But then when I set the field, either directly or using set(), I console log the changeset and it still only thinks there are two artifacts.  What might I be doing wrong?

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
      type: 'Changeset',
      success: function(model) {
             model.load( '1234', {
                  fetch: [ 'Artifacts' ],
                  callback: function(result, operation) {
                            if ( operation.wasSuccessful() ){
                                var artifacts = result.get('Artifacts');
                                if ( ! artifacts ) {
                                    artifacts = [];
                                }
                                artifacts.push( item );
                                console.log( artifacts );

                                result.data.Artifacts = artifacts;
                                //result.set('Artifacts', artifacts);

                                console.log( result );
                                result.save( {
                                    callback: function( result, operation ) {
                                    console.log( "After saving: ", operation );
                                    }
                                    } );
                            }
                   }
             })
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with a SaaS release over the weekend.  One can now send an array of artifacts and that array replaces the original list, like other arrays in the WSAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to create a new artifacts array, as its not marking the record as dirty when setting with the same array (probably a bug in Rally code or Ext code).
Also, you need to pass the data object of the artifact (in the example below, newUserStory.data).

I tweaked your code to make an example that creates a repository, changeset, and userstory; it then attaches that user story to the changeset's artifacts collection. 
If you run this code in it's entirety, you'll need to run each object creation separately from the update code, as its asynchronous, but dependent on each other. The other option would be to make callbacks inside each save() call.

Create the necessary domain objects:

```
   var newRepo, newChangeset, newUserStory;

Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
      type: 'SCMRepository',
      success: function(model) {
          newRepo = new model({
            Name: 'Repo1',
            SCMType: 'SCM Type 1'   
          });
          newRepo.save();
      }
});

Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
      type: 'Changeset',
      success: function(model) {
          newChangeset = new model({
            CommitTimestamp: '2012-06-20 01:00:00',
            Revision: 'revision1',
            SCMRepository: newRepo.data._ref
          });
          newChangeset.save();
      }
});


Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
      type: 'UserStory',
      success: function(model) {
          newUserStory = new model({
            Name: 'Test story ' + new Date()
          });
          newUserStory.save();
      }
});
```

Now update the changeset:

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
      type: 'Changeset',
      success: function(model) {
          model.load( newChangeset.data.ObjectID, {
                  fetch: [ 'Artifacts' ],
                  callback: function(result, operation) {
                      if ( operation.wasSuccessful() ){         
                            var artifacts = result.get('Artifacts'),
                                artifactsCopy = Ext4.Array.clone(artifacts);

                            artifactsCopy.push(newUserStory.data);
                            result.set('Artifacts', artifactsCopy);

                            result.save( {
                                callback: function( result, operation ) {
                                    if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                                        var artifactInUpdate = Ext4.Array.filter(result.data.Artifacts, function(artifact) {
                                            return artifact._ref === newUserStory.data._ref;
                                        });

                                        console.log('Userstory added to changeset:', artifactInUpdate.length > 0);
                                    } else { 
                                        console.log('update not successful');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                  }
           });
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I can't remove a story from the change set, though.